# Problema com pré-requisito de instalação

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, instalador

Tenho um projeto de instalador no Visual Studio 2013. Um dos pré-requisitos para a instalação é o IISExpress 7.5 ou maior.

Eu consegui colocar o IISExpress 7.5 como pré-requisito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, ao tentar instalar o aplicativo em um computador que possua o IISExpress 10, a instalação do IISExpress 7.5 é abortada, e meu aplicativo não é instalado. Quando removi o IIS10, consegui instalar o 7.5 então o aplicativo.

Como fazer para o instalador não instalar o IIS 7.5 se já tiver o 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que a verificação da versao falha, porque "10" é menor que "7" se voce usar a comparaçao string (ordem 1, 10,11...,100,1000,10000,2,20,21,3,4,5,6,7)

Eu creio que seja um bug que será resolvido logo, mas enquanto isso você pode editar manualmente a launch condition, como descrito aqui:
http://visualstudio2010yahya5.blogspot.ca/2015/08/iis-launch-condition-in-websetupproject_21.html

e aqui:
[IIS Launch Condition in WebSetupProject fails to detect IIS 10 on Win10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076795/iis-launch-condition-in-websetupproject-fails-to-detect-iis-10-on-win10/32386120#32386120)

Uma forma de resolver isso manualmente é utilizar o ORCA ou usar o seguinte método:

Abrir o Lauch Contidion Editor
[image: launch conditions]

Provavelmente voce vai enconrtar a formula:

```
 (IISMAJORVERSION >= "#5" AND IISMINORVERSION >= "#1") OR (IISMAJORVERSION >= "#6") or (IISMAJORVERSION >= "#7" AND IISMINORVERSION >= "#5")
```

Mude-a para:

```
(IISMAJORVERSION >= "#5" AND IISMINORVERSION >= "#1") OR (IISMAJORVERSION >= "#6") or (IISMAJORVERSION >= "#7" AND IISMINORVERSION >= "#5") or(IISMAJORVERSION >= "#10")
```

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Comment: No meu "launcher condition editor" só aparece ".NET Framework" em "lancher conditions". Eu adicionei o pré-requisito do "IISExpress 7.5" através do menu "Project/Setup1 Properties". Dessa forma é requisitado o "IIS Express". Em "search target machine" não tem nada.

Comment: Criei um instalador do tipo web, e apareceu essas configurações, porém a fórmula indicada não funcionou ainda.

Comment: Achei este artigo: https://forums.iis.net/p/1229532/2117546.aspx?Re+Unable+to+install+IIS+Database+Manager+x64+under+Windows+10+Pro+x64+ ,verifique se ele te ajuda, caso sim, eu traduzo e complemento minha resposta

Comment: Não deu certo, era pra dar, deve ser algo do ambiente. Mas de qualquer forma não vou precisar solucionar isso mais por n motivos. Vou aceitar a resposta pois trouxe bons exemplos e referências, e não funcionou talvez por algum pequeno detalhe que não estou com tempo pra ver.